# Detect sorting order in a folder

Tags: c#, windows, forms, sorting

I want to detect what sorting order I have chosen in a given path. My goal is to sort an array / list the same way.

For example: The path **C:\Test** is sorted after **lowest file size first**.
[image]

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you want to hook to explorer.exe and determine the sorting of the currently focussed instance? What have you tried so far?

Comment: No not focused, just a given path. I haven't seen any info on this issue so I haven't tried anything.

Comment: The ordering is applied by Windows Explorer when it shows the contents of that folder. Unless you want to dig into what kind of settings is persisted by Windows Explorer, that sorting is not observable by any other program.

Comment: What if the same folder is opened in two windows, and has different sorting in each window?

Comment: Then take the most recent sorting. Or the first, doesn't matter for me anyway.

Comment: You could implement sorting inside your software and store `Dictionary<path,sorting>` in its settings. Reusing windows explorer information has its cons. Many users prefer file managers. How would user change sorting if it's not provided? By exiting software, opening folder in explorer, changing sorting and starting software again? Unless you doing explorer/desktop extensions it doesn't feels right.

Comment: If you mean when I sort in explorer, my application should store that info in a .txt file or something, that's a great idea. But how do I detect when I click that Size^ in Explorer?

Comment: I don't have a windows computer at hand at the moment and this probably depends on the exact windows version, but I think it you click "Show hidden files" in your explorer, it should show a file that stores the explorer preferences for that folder. That file should contain the information you're interested in, although I don't know how easy it is to read and parse that file.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is in regaurds to the file enumeration methods in C#. Then the order of the files is not guaranteed and it depends on the file system. The operating system doesn't remember what you chose in windows explorer when you call the file enumeration methods in C#. Those methods are based on the [win32 apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea) which states the following

> The order in which this function returns the file names is dependent
> on the file system type. With the NTFS file system and CDFS file
> systems, the names are usually returned in alphabetical order. With
> FAT file systems, the names are usually returned in the order the
> files were written to the disk, which may or may not be in
> alphabetical order. However, as stated previously, these behaviors are
> not guaranteed.

However if you were an *enterprising-young-jedi-coder-with-time-to-burn*, you would likely find the sort order for windows explorer (as chosen by you in windows explorer) is *likely* stored in the registry. You could likely use a registry monitor to identify what is actually accessed and changed (if this is the case).

Personally I think this is likely going to take a long time, and OS dependent and may change with any windows update, for little to no benefit

Comment: But I use the old photo viewer in Win10: https://www.techsupportall.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Windows-Photo-Viewer.png When I click next picture I always get the next one in how my folder is sorted. I don't think the old photo viewer is updated anymore, so I don't think that the OS may change is an issue at least. I'm not sure or anything, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags` (good luck :)

Comment: You can also try with the Shell object. Actually, I don't remember whether the `IShellFolder` enumerator has an option to preserve the order currently selected. To verify.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Could you give a code example? I can't figure it out.

Comment: [IFolderView2::GetSortColumns()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview2-getsortcolumns) + [IFolderView2::GetSortColumnCount()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview2-getsortcolumncount)

Comment: @Jimi nice find!

Comment: Thanks, the description sounds like what I'm after! But is this not in C#? I can only see C++ code.

Comment: If you open a group of photos, then the data object for the group lists the items in the order they appear in the view. Photo Viewer when opened with a single photo will just go next in alphabetical order. (Note also that the user can have multiple windows open on the same folder, each with a different sort, so you're already stuck.)

Comment: If I set a folder to sort by Size for example, open one of the images with Photo Viewer, and hit next, the next in size will be shown. So not alphabetical order.